# freezing or locking a screen on the apple watch

Tags: watchkit

I have a certain screen in an apple watch application that I would like to lock or freeze, so that it displays when I rotate my wrist

Right now when I go to this screen and turn or move my wrist, the watch shuts off. Is there a way to prevent this from happening for a particular screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no WatchKit method that allows you to control the app suspension behavior.

Comment: What I thought. I don't suppose there is any way to programmatically "wake" the screen so it displays?

Comment: Sorry, but there is no programmatic method to wake the display. Basically, the user is always in control of when the app wakes up, and the user/OS is responsible for when it is suspended.